# How to solve the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(1-a)(1-a^2)\cdots(1-a^n)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

Suppose $|a|<1$ be a real number. How to solve the following limit?
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(1-a)(1-a^2)\cdots(1-a^n).$$

Comment: i think the limit is zero

Comment: Hmm... For $a=0$, it is not.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html. Wolfram is saying that this is not an obvious constant.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: The logarithm of the sequence is $\sum_n \log(1-a^n)$ in which the later terms are approximated well by $-a^n$. Since this geometric series converges, it is hard to imagine that $\sum_n \log(1-a^n)$ would diverge toward $-\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

This limit is the definition of the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function), a special function that doesn't seem to have any nicer closed form.