# Finding the value of the infinite product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \biggl(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\biggr)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, products, infinite-product

The math teacher of a friend of mine gave him this question on a test. He then asked me if I could solve it, but I had no idea how to begin. It goes like this.

Find the value of the following infinite product:
$$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \biggl(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\biggr)$$

It does indeed converge, but how does does one calculate the value? I did plug it into WolframAlpha, and the answer is about 0.288.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4093369/42969 or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1001151/42969

Comment: Yes, my bad. Closing the question. Thanks for pointing it out!