# Infinite product of $(1/2)\cdot(3/4)\cdot(7/8)\cdot(15/16)\cdot(31/32)\cdot\;\cdots\,$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

This problem has been bothering me for a while. I know that $$(1/2)\cdot(3/4)\cdot(7/8)\cdot(15/16)\cdot(31/32)\cdot\;\cdots$$ is convergent to something other than zero (around $0.2887$), but I do not know what the exact value of it is.

I have a basic understanding of math up to calc 1 (integrals are not very solid) but is there a way to solve this problem exactly? or will I have to stick with an approximation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128456/evaluate-prod-n-1-infty-frac2n-12n)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the value of the infinite product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \biggl(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\biggr)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336998/finding-the-value-of-the-infinite-product-prod-limits-n-1-infty-biggl1?noredirect=1&lq=1)